# How to remove particular character in a column in ms access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a ms access `table` which has a column named `description` which contains several records, There is a Space in the records which are of longer lengths, I need to remove the space which is in `26th` character. As i am new to access i find difficult to write queries, Any help would be greatly appreciated.
**For Example descrption column has few values like this** **:** MOXIFLOXACIN HYDROCHLORD**I** **E**/SODIUM CHLORIDE, There is a space between I and E, SO i need to concatenate it like this for all the records

MOXIFLOXACIN HYDROCHLORD**IE**/SODIUM CHLORIDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing characters can be a difficult concept.

If you want to remove the 26th character, you essentially should take all characters except the 26th character, which is the 25 characters to the left, and all characters higher than 27 to the right.

I'm checking inline if the string is longer than 26 characters, you might also decide to check that in a `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE myTable
Set MyColumn = Left(MyColumn, 25) & IIF(Len(MyColumn) > 26, Right(MyColumn, Len(MyColumn) - 26), "")
```

Comment: i am still not able to update properly, can you help me by writing in where clause

Comment: Please describe your error. I can't help if I don't know what's going wrong. As said, I'm checking inline, the statement should just work properly without a where clause. Just fill in your table and column name.

Comment: HM ALLERGY RELIEF & NASAL DECONGESTANT

Comment: VICKS NYQUIL SEVERE COLD & FLU MAX STRENGTH

Comment: few values like above dint got affected

Comment: Sorry, I can't troubleshoot that for you without more specifics. The only thing I can say is that it works fine with those values for me.